# Why am I getting unexpected string error?

Tags: javascript

When I create an object like this

```
var jim ={
name : "My Name",
skills: ["HTML 4/5", "CSS 2/3" "Joomla", "JavaScript" ,"jQuery , jQuery UI, jQuery UI mobile, jQUery Validation", "WCAG 2.0 AA"]
};
```

I get an SyntaxError: Unexpected string.. What gives?

Comment: `"CSS 2/3", "Joomla"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no comma after `"CSS 2/3"`.

Comment: oh crap ! Red faced. Thanks....

Comment: You also may need quotes around some of your array strings

Comment: @ElGavilan: If they're meant to be separate, yeah.

Comment: No I do not need the quotes. Those were meant 2 be that way. I was missing the comma only. Thanks